# USB esc_pos_printer Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, printers, flutter-windows

I want to print a flash with a USB printer in Flutter, but this library only has a network printer, I would be grateful if you could help me.
If it is possible with this library, please let me know. If not, there is no problem with another library
I tried all the libraries but it didn't work